# Setting ID for a BrowserView

Tags: javascript, electron

BrowserView.getAllViews() shows me a list of all BrowserViews as

```
[ BrowserView {}, BrowserView {}, BrowserView {} ]
```

BrowserView.fromId(id) should help me select one of them, I guess. But I don't understand how to set a unique id for a BrowserView.

The actual problem I have, in case you suggest another solution:
How do I keep my BrowserViews organized and select specific ones to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window to distinguish your browserview, as every browserview has uniqe tagId, just like this:
view.webContents.executeJavaScript("window.**tagId** = 'a test id' ");

then 
view.webContents.executeJavaScript("window.**tagId**") to get tagId, which will help you to distinguish.

If your browserView need reload, you can use webContents.preload property to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to deal, after you new the browserview, you will get the **id** in your browerview's webcontents

So  you just store the **id** form browserview which one you want, and put in a variable

when get the browserview you want, can forEach the browserviews by webcontents.id

look that key code

```
let youwantViewId: number = 0
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
const view = new BrowserView({
    webPreferences:{}
})
mainWindow.addBrowserView(view)
view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600 })
view.webContents.loadURL('https://XXXXXX/public/office-prefetch/office-prefetch.html')
youwantViewId = view.webContents.id
// ------------------------------------
setTimeout(() => {
 mainWindow.getBrowserViews().forEach((item) => {
  if (item.webContents.id === youwantViewId) {
    console.error(item)
  }
 })
},5000)
```